# Paypal express check out stopped working with ci-merchant

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, express-checkout, ci-merchant

Experts I have integrated paypal express checkout with ci_merchant and i was using sandbox accounts for testing. It was working fine but suddenly now its is giving response like "You do not have permissions to make this API call". I have goggled and found I need to set api permission and enable express checkout I did it but still the same response. Can anyone help me?

http://help.tictail.com/customer/portal/articles/1063813-paypal-error-%22you-do-not-have-permissions-to-make-this-api-call%22

I have tried above link sollution.

here is request array

```
  Array ( [METHOD] => SetExpressCheckout [VERSION] => 85.0 
[USER] => takeout_api1.rest.com 
[PWD] => 1369227981 
[SIGNATURE] => AnOQDpMvzNQqHN5u7vb9BKLaKYLoALq6R0g3ohOwD4RQgO0DQDI5l7V4     
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION] => Authorization
 [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT] => 121.00
 [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE] => USD 
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC] => 
[SOLUTIONTYPE] => Sole 
[LANDINGPAGE] => Billing 
[NOSHIPPING] => 1 
[ALLOWNOTE] => 0 
[RETURNURL] => https://www.mealordering.net/payment/pay/2/265 
[CANCELURL] => https://www.mealordering.net/payment/pay/2/265
 [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME] => 
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET] => 
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2] => 
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY] => 
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE] => 
[PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE] =>
 [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP] =>
 [PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM] =>
 [EMAIL] => )
```

`HERE CONTROLLER NAME IS PAYMENT and paypal and pay methods I am using for making php api or ci-merchant library call`

```
public function paypal($rest_id,$orderid)
    {
         $this->merchant->load('paypal_express');
     $settings = $this->merchant->default_settings();
        $settings = array(
                            'username' => $get_payapl->LoginId,
                            'password' => $get_payapl->SecretKey,
                            'signature' => $get_payapl->Signature,
                            'test_mode' => true,
                            );
                        $this->merchant->initialize($settings);

        $return_url=site_url('payment/pay/'.$rest_id.'/'.$orderid);
        $cancel_url=site_url('payment/pay/'.$rest_id.'/'.$orderid);
     $params = array(
                        'amount' => $payable_amt,
                        'currency' => $cuurency_code->CurrencyCode,
                        'return_url' => $return_url,
                        'cancel_url' => $cancel_url
                        );
        $response = $this->merchant->purchase($params);

}


public function pay($rest_id,$orderid)
    {
     $this->merchant->load('paypal_express');
    settings = $this->merchant->default_settings();
        $settings = array(
                            'username' => $get_payapl->LoginId,
                            'password' => $get_payapl->SecretKey,
                            'signature' => $get_payapl->Signature,
                            'test_mode' => true,
                            );
        $return_url=site_url('payment/pay/'.$rest_id.'/'.$orderid);
        $cancel_url=site_url('payment/pay/'.$rest_id.'/'.$orderid);
    $params = array(
                        'amount' => $payable_amt,
                        'currency' => $cuurency_code->CurrencyCode,
                        'return_url' => $return_url,
                        'cancel_url' => $cancel_url
                        );

        $response = $this->merchant->purchase_return($params);//final response this is

    if ($response->success())
           {
                //success message and code
           }
            else
            {
              //fail messages and code
           }
  }
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a vendor support issue (account/setup, etc).

Answer (score 0):

That error typically doesn't happen with Express Checkout unless the account from which you pulled the API credentials is a personal account instead of a business account.  Is there a chance you changed the credentials to some other account, and that account is not a business account?

Comment: Its a business account . Though I will double check it and get back to you. thanks for the response

Comment: Account is perfect . Its the business account. And Its working with express checkout api for android. As we have also made android app for same website

Comment: Can you post a sample of the API request that you're sending?

Comment: Hi @Andrew I have edited code and posted code which is related to paypal

Comment: I wasn't looking for the PHP code that generates the request, but rather the request itself that gets sent to PayPal.  The library must be generating that somewhere.

Comment: here you go. Now see the edited question I have printed request array

Comment: Can you try changing from Auth to Sale and see if it works then?

Comment: still the same response